How do I generate random queries using tpch's qgen tool?
I tried to use this tool to generate 2200 different sql statements from the template. Mentioned in https://github.com/databricks/tpch-dbgen,- r parameter can be used to specify the seed. However, I run this statement, but the result is the same queries.
for i in seq 22;do ./qgen -d $i -s 1 -r 100 > outputfile/queries/$i.sql; done

I tried to change -r for a larger number, but I still get same queries.

One seed could only produce one query. You could give a random seed to generate different queries, like
./qgen -d $i -s 1 -r $RANDOM
